# C++ Semantic issue: "'use of undeclared identifier 'balance'"

Tags: c++, semantics

I am new to C++ and using Xcode and I am having an issue,
in my main .cpp file Account.cpp the code is-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include "Account.h"
Account::Account()

{
    double balance=0;
    balance=0;
}
Account getbalance()
{
    return balance;
}

void deposit(double amount)
{
    balance+=amount;
}
void withdraw(double amount)
{
    balance-=amount;
}
void addInterest(double interestRate)
{
    balance=balance*(1+interestRate);
}
```

I think I missed something but I'm not sure where, any help would be appreciated thank you.

**The header file Account.h is-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Account
{
private:
    double balance;
public:
    Account();
    Account(double);
    double getBalance();
    void deposit(double amount);

    void withdraw(double amount);
    void addInterest(double interestRate);
};
```

Comment: `double balance=0; balance=0;` What?

Comment: Moreover it looks like you're missing `Account::` in a few places. And by the error I'm *guessing* you've not declared `balance` as a member, but without having seen the class declaration I can but guess.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include it, it's very hard to read in a comment. But at a glance it looks like the missing `Account::`s are the (current) problem. Then come the mismatching return types.

Comment: Alright @Biffen sorry about that, is that better?

Comment: More readable, certainly. But your code is still a mess. Might I suggest reading a tutorial or book?

Comment: Yes I have gone through a couple tutorials on youtube, but still can't quite figure what exactly I am messing up.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't think YouTube videos to be a very good medium for such things, but to each their own, I suppose. As for what you're messing up I'm afraid it's a number of things. Hence my previous recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the constructor the following way

```
Account::Account()
{
    balance = 0.0;
}
```

I suppose that `balance` is a data member of type `double` of class Account.

Or you can write

```
Account::Account() : balance( 0.0 ) {}
```

And all these function definitions if the functions are class member functions must look at least like

```
double Account::getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}

void Account::deposit(double amount)
{
    balance+=amount;
}
void Account::withdraw(double amount)
{
    balance-=amount;
}
void Account::addInterest(double interestRate)
{
    balance=balance*(1+interestRate);
}
```

Also it seems that you forgot to define the constructor with a parameter.

```
Account::Account( double initial_balance ) : balance( initial_balance ) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Vlad! So, if I am understanding correctly, the second edit is regarding my header file, and the first and last edit are for my main function file?

Comment: @sdubs177 I showed changes that you should do in Account.cpp file.

Comment: For the line of code- double Account; Account::getbalance() it is giving me the error "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations"

Comment: @sdubs177 It was a typo. There should be double Account::getBalance(). See my updated post.

Comment: @sdubs177 The function should be named getBalance.

Comment: @sdubs177 Beginners should help each other.:)

Comment: You helped a ton, and I couldn't agree more! @Vlad from Moscow